# SwiftUI - Styling Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, uipickerview

I have a Picker like this:

[image]

Im trying to change the style so it pops up like the keyboard does, see example:

[image]

This is my code at the moment:

```
Picker(selection: $profileViewModel.age, label: Text("Age")) {
     ForEach(0 ..< 100) { number in
          Text("\(number)")
     }
}.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo of some approach... tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Spacer()
        Divider()
        Picker(selection: $age, label: Text("Age")) {
             ForEach(0 ..< 100) { number in
                  Text("\(number)")
             }
        }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom))
    }

}
```

Comment: This works if there are no other fields with the picker, otherwise it just styles the picker in the same place. Im looking for something like, when i click the field this style picker would appear. just like when you click a text field the keyboard slides up

Comment: I provided a demo how this styling could be done, making it conditional, w/ or w/o transitions, animations, etc... is context specific and is up to you. Nobody but you can imaging how to adapt something into workflow of your project.